# Cloud Functions for Firebase sometimes have Invalid credential error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Not appear every time, but sometimes this error appears in the log:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"read ECONNRESET\"."}
```

Is there any way to handle this kind of error like retry?
Or is it okay to ignore it?

Comment: May not related to the warning, but I got this error: "Error: Could not load the default credentials. Browse to https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information." on my firebase error log. The function failed to execute.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058274/google-cloud-functions-with-econnreset-errors-until-i-redeploy/43149553#43149553

Answer (score 0):

Just ensure that your machine time auto sync. and not manualy,

And your `XXX......json` from firebase is the latest downloaded. (if you dont sure, download it again - and this file will be the newer one)

that what helped me.

Comment: What do you mean by "Just ensure that your machine time auto sync. and not manualy,"

Comment: The local time in your server

Answer (score -1):

I am also facing this issue. Looks like it retries and get the job done but cloud functions are taking time to process data.