# Google Cloud Functions with ECONNRESET errors until I redeploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Google Cloud Functions to:

1. Watch for a new Firebase entry
2. Download a file that's referenced in the Firebase entry
3. Generate a thumbnail based on that file.
4. Upload the thumbnail to the cloud bucket.

Unfortunately I'm getting `ECONNRESET` errors repeatedly on step 4, and the only way to fix it seems to be to redeploy the function. Any ideas how to further debug this?

Edit:

It seems like many times when this happens, when I try to deploy the function again, it errors, and I have to run the deploy twice. Is something hanging or something?

[image]

Comment: Do report it on cloud functions beta forum. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/cloud-functions-beta-testers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Update May 9 2017

According to [this thread](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node/issues/2254#issuecomment-299609092), the google cloud nodejs API developers have made some changes to the defaults that are used when initializing that should solve these ECONNRESET socket issues.

From @stephen++ on github GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node issue 2254:

> We have disabled the forever agent by default in Cloud Function
>   environments. If you un- and re-install @google-cloud/storage, you
>   will pick up the new behavior automatically. Thanks for all of the
>   helpful debugging, everyone!

---

#### Older Post Follows:

The solution for me to similar `ECONNRESET` issues using storage on the cloud functions platform was to use `npm:promise-retry`, but set up your own retry strategy because the default of 10 retries is too many.

I reported an [ECONNRESET issue with cloud functions to Google Support](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36667671) (which you might star if you are also getting ECONNRESET in this context but not in other contexts) and they replied with a "won't fix" that the behavior is expected.  Google support said the socket that the API client library uses to connect times out after a few minutes, and then when your cloud function tries to use it again you get ECONNRESET. They recommended adding `autoRetry:true` when initializing the storage API, but that did not help.

The ECONNRESETs happen on the read side too.  In both read and write cases `promise-retry` helps, and most of the time with only 1 retry needed to reset the bad socket.

So I wrote [`npm:pipe-to-storage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pipe-to-storage) to return a promise to do the retries, check md5, etc., but I haven't tested it with binary data, only text, so I don't know if you could use it with image files.  The calls would look like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage')();
const pipeToStorage = require('pipe-to-storage')(storage);
const source = ()=>(fs.createReadStream("/path/to/your/file/to/upload"));
pipeToStorage(source, bucketName, fileNameInBucket).then(//do next step);
```

See also [How do I read the contents of a new cloud storage file of type .json from within a cloud function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43014341/how-do-i-read-the-contents-of-a-new-cloud-storage-file-of-type-json-from-within/43014342#43014342)

Answer (score 0):

You can directly report a bug to the [Firebase Support team](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), or open a [support ticket](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) with Firebase to troubleshoot a specific issue.

You may also report a Cloud Functions specific issue in the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187195&template=802601), which is similar to Stack Overflow in that it is accessible by the public (but specifically used for filing issue reports).