# ECONRESET socket hungup

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a function that triggers on firebase database onWrite. The function body use two google cloud apis (DNS and Storage).

While the function is running and working as expected (mostly), the issue is that the Socket hang up more often than I'd like. (50%~ of times)

My questions are:
Is it similar to what the rest of the testers have experienced? Is it a well known issue that is outstanding or expected behavior?

the example code is as follows:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {credentials} = functions.config().auth;
credentials.private_key = credentials.private_key.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
const config = Object.assign({}, functions.config().firebase, {credentials});
admin.initializeApp(config);
const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({credentials});
const dns = require('@google-cloud/dns')({credentials});
const zoneName = 'applambda';
const zone = dns.zone(zoneName);

exports.createDeleteDNSAndStorage = functions.database.ref('/apps/{uid}/{appid}/name')
.onWrite(event => {
    // Only edit data when it is first created.
    const {uid, appid} = event.params;
    const name = event.data.val();
    const dbRef = admin.database().ref(`/apps/${uid}/${appid}`);

    if (event.data.previous.exists()) {
        console.log(`already exists ${uid}/${appid}`);
        return;
    }
    // Exit when the data is deleted.
    if (!event.data.exists()) {
        console.log(`data is being deleted ${uid}/${appid}`);
        return;
    }

    const url = `${name}.${zoneName}.com`;
    console.log(`data: ${uid}/${appid}/${name}\nsetting up: ${url}`);

    setupDNS({url, dbRef});
    setupStorage({url, dbRef});
    return;
});

function setupDNS({url, dbRef}) {

    // Create an NS record.
    let cnameRecord = zone.record('cname', {
        name: `${url}.`,
        data: 'c.storage.googleapis.com.',
        ttl: 3000
    });

    zone.addRecords(cnameRecord).then(function() {
        console.log(`done setting up zonerecord for ${url}`);
        dbRef.update({dns: url}).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(`error setting up zonerecord for ${url}`);
        console.error(err);
    });
}

function setupStorage({url, dbRef}) {
    console.log(`setting up storage bucket for ${url}`);

    gcs.createBucket(url, {
        website: {
            mainPageSuffix: `https://${url}`,
            notFoundPage: `https://${url}/404.html`
        }
    }).then(function(res) {
        let bucket = res[0];
        console.log(`created bucket ${url}, setting it as public`);
        dbRef.update({storage: url}).then(function() {
            console.log(`done setting up bucket for ${url}`);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.error(`db update for storage failed ${url}`);
            console.error(err);
        });
        bucket.makePublic().then(function() {
            console.log(`bucket set as public for ${url}`);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.error(`setting public for storage failed ${url}`);
            console.error(err);
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        console.error(`creating bucket failed ${url}`);
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43058274/google-cloud-functions-with-econnreset-errors-until-i-redeploy/43149553#43149553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking your function needs to return a promise so that all the other async work has time to complete before the function shuts down.  As it's shown now, your functions simply returns immediately without waiting for the work to complete.

I don't know the cloud APIs you're using very well, but I'd guess that you should make your `setupDns()` and `setupStorage()` return the promises from the async work that they're doing, then return `Promise.all()` passing those two promises to let Cloud Functions know it should wait until all that work is complete before cleaning up the container that's running the function.

Comment: I've realized that after I posted the question. However, random resets still happen, perhaps not that often though I have no way to judge if the frequency has decreased. I'll try what Paul suggested in his comment and report back if it fixes