# BigQuery read ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

When using Firebase Cloud Functions in combination with Google BigQuery. Sometimes an error is thrown randomly when this function is triggered.

This is our error log:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:569:26)
```

And here the code my colleague made.

```
const bigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const database = admin.database();

exports.updateAllPlaceStatistics = (request, response) => {
    const secret = request.query['secret'];

    if (secret !== 'secret') {
        return response.json({message: 'Request failed!'});
    }

    const big = bigQuery();

    return big.query({
        query: [
            'SELECT place.id, COUNT(DISTINCT beacon.id) as beacons, COUNT(DISTINCT promotion.id) as promotions, placeUsers.users as users',
            'FROM `omega.sw_places` as place',
            'LEFT JOIN `omega.sw_promotions` as promotion ON promotion.place_id = place.id',
            'LEFT JOIN `omega.sw_beacons` as beacon ON beacon.place_id = place.id',
            'LEFT JOIN `omega.view_users_per_place` as placeUsers ON placeUsers.id = place.id',
            'GROUP BY place.id, placeUsers.users'
        ].join(' '),
        params: []
    }).then((data) => {
        const rows = data[0];

        let result = {};
        for (let index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
            const item = rows[index];

            result[item.id] = {
                beacons: item.beacons,
                promotions: item.promotions
            };
        }

        return database.ref('statistics/general').set(result);
    }).then(() => {
        return response.json({message: 'Request succeeded!'});
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('An error has happened to the big_query.js');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(error));

        return response.json({message: 'Request failed!'});
    });
};
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/43058274/5221944

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `return` from `return database.ref('statistics/general').set(result);`

Returning a promise resolved ends function execution. In this case, your `.set()` ends before BigQuery which ends the function before BigQuery can.