# Cloud Functions for Firebase BigQuery sync error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

We're working on a cloud function that allows us to keep our bigquery and firebase database in sync. The function triggers when a place is created/updated/deleted.

Based on the trigger action (create/update/delete) we add a property called big_query_active to signal if the object exists or not. Same goes for the date.

Our current problem is that the call to big query sometimes returns an error. So that would mean that the data is not in sync anymore. How can this be prevented?

```
'use strict';

// Default imports.

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const bigQuery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

// If you want to change the nodes to listen to REMEMBER TO change the constants below.
// The 'id' field is AUTOMATICALLY added to the values, so you CANNOT add it.

const ROOT_NODE = 'places';
const VALUES = [
    'country_id',
    'category_id',
    'name',
    'active',
    'archived'
];

// This function listens to the supplied root node, but on child added/removed/changed.
// When an object is inserted/deleted/updated the appropriate action will be taken.

exports.children = functions.database.ref(ROOT_NODE + '/{id}').onWrite(event => {
    const query = bigQuery();
    const dataset = query.dataset('stampwallet');
    const table = dataset.table(ROOT_NODE);

    if (!event.data.exists() && !event.data.previous.exists()) {
        return;
    }

    const item = event.data.exists() ? event.data.val() : event.data.previous.val();

    const data = {};

    data['id'] = event.params.id;

    for (let index = 0; index < VALUES.length; index++) {
        const key = VALUES[index];
        data[key] = item[key] !== undefined ? item[key] : null;
    }

    data['big_query_date'] = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    data['big_query_active'] = event.data.exists();

    return table.insert(data).then(() => {
        return true;
    }).catch((error) => {
        if (error.name === 'PartialFailureError') {
            console.log('A PartialFailureError happened while uploading to BigQuery...');
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            console.log('Random error happened while uploading to BigQuery...');
        }
    });
});
```

This is the error that we (sometimes) receive

```
{"code":"ECONNRESET","errno":"ECONNRESET","syscall":"read"}
```

How could it be prevented that the data goes out of sync? Or is there a way to retry so that it always succeeds?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/q/43058274/5221944